# Google Sheets: Change value in active cell dynamically?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to change a cell value based on a color change... When I change the color in the cell nothing happens. No text gets set for the cell.

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(status)
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();    
}

function status() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();  // Returns the active cell

  var currentColor = cell.getBackgroundColor();

  switch(true) {
    case currentColor === '#ffdc32':
      cell.setValue('IN PROGRESS');
      break;

    case currentColor === 'green':
      cell.setValue('COMPLETED');
      break;

    case currentColor === 'red':
      cell.setValue('ERRORS');
      break;

  }

}
```

Comment: You want to set the value of a cell based on color? If so, what happens when you try your code? That looks like a great starting point, sans the getting part.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell - When I change the color nothing happens. No text gets set for the cell.

Comment: You should probably include that detail in your question then. Have you set up an `onEdit` trigger for this function?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell: I was just looking into triggers but haven't figured them out yet.

Comment: Would I create an onEdit trigger and add my status function to it?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell how do I run my status function from the onEdit trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this out and noticed two things. First, you have to use the hex code for the color instead of the name, i.e. `#ff0000` instead of `red`. Also, it seems that changing the background color of a cell is not considered an edit. So if you change the color of the cell then type anything in it (even a single space will do), upon exiting the cell the text will change to what you want. The following works for me - I used a single `onEdit(e)` instead of a full on trigger, and did the switch based on the color:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var cell = e.source.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();

  var currentColor = cell.getBackgroundColor();

  switch (currentColor){

    case '#ffdc32':
      cell.setValue('IN PROGRESS');
      break;

    case '#00ff00':
      cell.setValue('COMPLETED');
      break;

    case '#ff0000':
      cell.setValue('ERRORS');
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the function to trigger, you need to setup a trigger, either a simple or installable.

The easiest way is to rename your function to `onEdit`, this will automatically act as a simple trigger.

Alternatively, you can setup an installable trigger by going to the `Resources` menu, and to `Current Projects Triggers`, click the `no triggers setup...` text and then select your function, select from spreadsheet, then select on edit, like the picture below.

[image]

[image]

[Simple Triggers Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopen)

[Installable Triggers Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers)

Comment: Still not working. I even tried adding the code to my original code... See my original code (edited).

Comment: @sbaden Oh, I see. You are using a function on the cell. You can't set the value of the cell the function is ran from, you need to return a value. I will edit my post when I am back at my computer.

Comment: I removed the function on the cell when I created the trigger. The trigger should work for any cell that is edited right? My function is getting the active cell.

Comment: @sbaden, you don't need to programmatically create a trigger like you did in your code. Follow the above instructions and try that.

Comment: I followed the above directions and it still isn't working. Does the trigger recognize a color change as an edit?

Comment: @sbaden I am not 100% sure on the color change triggering the edit trigger. I will investigate further when I am home and provide an example sheet with the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Douglas. I really appreciate all your help!